# Why MVC Upload file cannot take word file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created file upload form using MVC. It can upload pdf, image, txt, etc. files but not Microsoft word file. The column datatype is varbinary(Max).
controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {

        byte[] bytes;
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
        {
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);
        }
        string constr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDataModel"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO mytable (filedata,mimetype) VALUES (@filepath, @filedata,@mimetype)";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filepath", Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mimetype", postedFile.ContentType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filedata", bytes);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }

        }
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    {

        <input type="file" name="postedFile" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" />
    }

}
```

where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What type of server are you using? IIS?

Comment: What's the upload's error?

Comment: Where is the problem? You tell us. Do you get an error? What happens?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web server settings to see if .docx files are allowed file types:

MIME Type:
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

This varies depending on the type and version of web server.

From memory in IIS, right click the website node > HTTP Headers > Mime Types.

Comment: I am currently testing from my local machine. The error message is "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated." Thanks.

Comment: Is it a docx file or alternate type?

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification

Comment: Yes, it is .docx file.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it is throwing an exception at the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Does the variable bytes have value when the using statement begins? If so it appears the file got to the server (even if it was local) and my mime type suggestion is not the problem and is failing at the database insert.

Comment: The word document bytes was read but failed when run the  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); The excel file cannot be inserted into the database either.

Comment: So it looks I cannot upload word or Excel file into the SQL database. Could this be database server issue?

Comment: I created the form using .net web form instead of MVC and I can upload word, Excel, etc. files without any problem. Not sure where the problem is on MVC.